# Can not select specific UITableViewCell after reloading tableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

My UITableView shows answers for questions.
To switch questions I apply CATransition to tableView and call reloadData method.
In case if user did select one row, went to another question and then returned back to the first question, I want the chosen answer to be selected.
I call

```
[tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath
                   animated:YES
             scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];
```

in delegate method

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

But when answers appear after reloading UITableView, there are no selected cells. If I move cell out of the screen and then move it back, it becomes selected.

Comment: Have you solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

you need to implement following `UITableView delegate` method to perform any action on selection of cell

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath     {
   // [self doSomethingWithRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
// write your action on cell here
}
```

Comment: it is already implemented. I've said that cell becomes highlighted only when i get it out of screen bounds and return back. So, selection works, but not after reloading tableView data.

Comment: you can update visible cells by `reloading visible cells` or `reload inputviews` of cell or `reload particular cell`. This will work only if you have set proper conditions to highlight it